# How to convert two columns values into a key-value pair dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert values from the columns from the DataFrame below to a key-value pair dictionary like `{"a": 29, "b": 1042, "c": 2928, "d": 4492}`

```
    event_type  count
0   a           29
1   b           1042
2   c           2928
3   d           4492
```

Comment: ```df.to_dict()```

Comment: This does not produce the expected result @joan You'd need a Series, as in jezrael's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `Series` and convert to `dict`:

```
d = df.set_index('event_type')['count'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'a': 29, 'b': 1042, 'c': 2928, 'd': 4492}
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is using `zip`:

```
dict(zip(*df.values.T))
# {'a': 29, 'b': 1042, 'c': 2928, 'd': 4492}
```

If the dataframe contains more columns:

```
dict(zip(df['event_type'], df['count']))
# {'a': 29, 'b': 1042, 'c': 2928, 'd': 4492}
```

Comment: would this work with dataframe contain more than two columns?

Comment: Updated with an alternative for such case @LoremIpsumDolor